# How to read cookies in rails app set by some different application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

I need to read cookies set by some different application into my rails application. both the application is running under common SSO (authentication) and when the user successfully authenticated he first redirected to the first application (Node/Express app) which write some data into browser cookies and then when the user clicks on some button which loads my rails application. it will create a rails session. I need to set some variables reading from the cookie set by node/express application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SSO cookie is named "sso_cookie", to read the cookie: `cookies[:sso_cookie]`. To update the cookie: `cookies[:sso_cookie] = 'new-value'`.

See [ActionDispatch::Cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

Comment: I am not able to get the cookie key in cookie object. If I need to access cross-domain cookies and decrypt it then what is the best way

Comment: You can't share cookies across domains. You may find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies#3342225